# How to fresh install ubuntu 12.04 without removing windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation, removing

I have both Ubuntu and Windows 7 on my computer. I want to fresh install Ubuntu 12.04. 
I want to remove older Ubuntu and install Ubuntu 12.04 without any changes on Windows 7.
I know I can upgrade and all. But I decided I want fresh install.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Back up your data from both operating systems.
Make a live USB or CD of the desired version the same way you did before.
Boot from it.
Then choose to install and during the procedure select `install alongside` and, when prompted, allow the installation procedure to `overwrite` the current Ubuntu installation. At your discretion, you may choose to retain the /home folder or wipe that as well. 
That's all.

Comment: thanks's mate. If I had enough reputation, I would have voted up your question.

Comment: Boot from live usb. Install Gparted. Delete the drives contains ubuntu os. Start installation. Choose custom layout. Create new partitions from the free space. Install it. Create two partitions /boot and swap. Install.